# cors angular/node +express issue

Tags: angular, express, cors

I know there are a bunch of stuff about how to enable CORS in node/express and have tried implementing those, but with no luck.

My request in angular:

```
function getPhotos(location) {
      var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=' + location.lat + '&lng=' + location.lng + '&access_token=' + ig_access_token;
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
      }).then(function (response) {
        console.log("here are the photos: ", response);
      }, function(err) {
        console.log("whoops, there is an error: ", err);
    });
```

and my server setup in node/express:

```
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));

 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port);`
```

but I still keep getting this error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

Any ideas?

Comment: CORS needs to be enabled on the server that is receiving the request. Enabling it on your Express server won't make any difference.

Comment: Use the CORS package for Express: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in your angular code

```js
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
    }
  })
```